# Properly handle angular route from a different virtual directory at server level

Tags: asp.net, angular, iis, routes

I have **two virtual directories** in an IIS site.

- One is used for a **asp mvc web api** application.
- The other one is used to serve an **angular 4 SPA**.

The SPA rely on the web api application for its data.

We use the dist output of @angular/cli for the SPA content that is used as the physical path to the second virtual directory.

I'm looking for a way to catch angular routes directly forwarded to the server (i.e.: before the angular app has loaded client-site).

For the sake of clarity, here is my two applications as configured under my site in my applicationhost.config :

```
<site name="MySite" id="9292">
  ...
  <application path="/spa" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
      <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\angularApp\dist" />
  </application>
  <application path="/webApi" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
      <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\webApiAspMvcApp" />
  </application>
  ...
  <bindings>
    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:9292:localhost" />
  </bindings>
</site>
```

Saying I have the following angular route configured in my angular application : `"about/company"`, I'm looking for a way to handle the call to `http://localhost:9292/spa/about/company`, for IIS not to try serving static content at this location.

Of course the real static content as-used by the spa should still be served by IIS.